# How does Parity signer token works?

Tags: parity, parity-signer

Some points I want to understand:

1. Why it exists given we can authorize the transaction with password.
2. What does generate a new token means?
3. Can I have multiple tokens?
4. How to revoke a token?
5. Is there further plan of it? It seems to be exclusive Parity.

The resources about the trusted token is quite limited, thanks in advanced:)

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why it exists given we can authorize the transaction with password.

The Secure Transaction Signer is a core piece of technology which ensures that no transaction can be sent from your accounts without your explicit approval. This means that you can interact with DApps without fear that they might attempt to drain your accounts.

When a transaction request is made, you'll have to use the Signer UI to authenticate the request before the transaction can be signed relayed to the network. This is made to be as seamless as possible, and you can rest easy knowing your Ether is protected.

> 2. What does generate a new token means?

Generating a new token allows you to authorize your browser session, or: it proves you are allowed to use the wallet. This means DApps can't access your Wallet without having to ask you for a token or creating a signer request from within an active session.

> 3. Can I have multiple tokens?

Yes, if you want to run multiple sessions, or use multiple browsers at the same time. But usually, you do not want that.

> 4. How to revoke a token?

By removing the token from the authcodes file:

`~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/signer/authcodes`

> 5. Is there further plan of it? It seems to be exclusive Parity.

Yes, this feature is exclusive for Parity so far.

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*